# Generating vouchers using md5?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

new here.
I'm trying to generate 100000 vouchers and send them to a database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(5400);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$connection = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
$db = mysql_select_db("...", $connection);

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

for ($i=0;$i<100000;$i++){
    $voucher = substr(md5($i), 0, 6);
    $query = mysql_query("insert into voucher(nr_voucher) values ($voucher)");
}
    mysql_close($connection);
```

?>

The result is wrong number of rows (when testing with 1000 it returned 67 rows) and weird hexa that the first 6 digits of md5 shouldn't be, like "2.8e21" and "0".
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is apparent that it is casting the hexadecimal value into a numeric as though it is a string, not a hexadecimal value. For example, 285e19 (one of your voucher values) is becoming 2.8e21. Similarly, b70683 will become 0 because b is not a valid way to start a number. I suggest making nr_vouicher a char(6) field and inserting '$voucher'.

Comment: Better change your filed type to varchar and set length 60 and use transaction command. If execute all will execute otherwise noting will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CONV('123ab', 16, 10)` --> `74667`

That is one way to convert from hex to decimal.

Be warned that you are very likely to get a few duplicates when converting 100000 24-bit 'random' numbers to decimal.  It won't be nearly as bad as 933/1000 like what you got.